# How can I prove two empirically derived graphs are topologically equivalent?

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, algebraic-topology, approximation

I have two graphs that I've derived from an empirical data set and I suspect that they're topologically equivalent.  It seems much easier to show that these graphs are not equivalent than to show that they are.  For example, I've used persistent homology, but have been unable to show that they weren't equivalent.  Are there any methods/techniques for this?

Further, I would be happy to know whether or not the graphs are approximately topologically equivalent.  Are there any methods/techniques for this?

Comment: The graph isomorphism problem is know to be a NP problem (but not a hard one ... but we don't know whether it is in P or not ... it is a strange problem ...). So most probably an algorithm to solve your problem would be expensive. But some cases are known to be polynomial, you may want to see the wikipedia page to see if your graph lies in one of the easy category: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem